# How BLE peripheral use advertising packets send data to iphone(BLE center) APP in lock screen mode?

Tags: iphone

how can iphone APP receive Advertising packets from BLE peripheral in the lock screen mode?

The BLE peripheral(chip nRF51822) sends Advertising packets with temperature data to iphone APP every 30min.

My codes:

```
UInt16 service2 = BLE_UUID_HEALTH_THERMOMETER_SERVICE;
    service2 = [self swap:service2];
    NSData *serviceData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(char *)&service2 length:2];
    NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithData:serviceData2]];
    [self.centeralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services    options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
```

iPhone app can work well in "background mode", almost no advertising packet loss.

But the advertising packet data losed when iphone screen black. 
Once I drag out the Control Center of iPhone, or slide to unlock the iPhone, APP can work well again.

Is it any example code for ios app get the BLE adv packet data in the case of lock screen?